# My while statement isnt working with my BigDecimal

Tags: loops, while-loop, bigdecimal

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Creates the BigDecimal and scanner used
    BigDecimal answer = new BigDecimal("0");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //While statement to repeat if they dont answer 1 or 2
    while (! answer.equals("1") && ! answer.equals("2")) {
        //Asks user to input the number 1 or 2
        System.out.print("Enter the number 1 or 2: ");
        //Takes in users answer
        answer = scan.nextBigDecimal(); 
    }

    //Uses printf to print what they typed in
    System.out.printf("You entered the number %s.", answer);
    scan.close();

}
```

This code is not working and I'm wondering why. The problem seems to be in the while statement and I cant seem to find the issue. Please help

Comment: Please explain what “not working” means. Does it compile? Does it compile but throws an error? What is the error message? Does it run but not give the right answer? What answer does it give?

Answer (score 1):

here

```
while (! answer.equals("1") && ! answer.equals("2")) {
```

you are comparing BigDecimal object to strings "1" and "2".

How about this?

```
while (! answer.equals(new BigDecimal("1")) && ! answer.equals(new BigDecimal("2"))) {
```